# In SQLAlchemy, how can I make enum type names use undescores in the database?

Tags: python, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

You can use `__tablename__` in SQLAlchemy to give names to your tables. It seems like there is no equivalent way to do this with enum types.

See an enum I have defined here:

```
class NumberBought(enum.Enum):
    very_low = 'very_low'
    low = 'low'
    medium = 'medium'
    high = 'high'
    very_high = 'very_high'
```

Here is how it appears in pgAdmin:

[image]

I want a way to put underscores in the name so it reads `number_bought` in the actual database rather than `numberbought`.

I've tried a few pieces of possible syntax, as well as looked through various StackOverflow answers and the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) to do so, but haven't found a way.

1. Is this possible to do, and how?
2. If this is not possible, could it cause problems if there are 2 enums with the same name (e.g. 2 different enums called "Product" or "Price")

Comment: Pass an explicit name: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum.params.name

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. You need to add `name` to the Column definition containing the `sa.Enum type`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Test'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Enum(NumberBought, name='number_bought'))
```

If you want to use the same `enum` in another table you also need to use the same definition including the name as above.

Comment: Please have a look at [Someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)